# Did Aristotle really apply the term 'accent'?

Tags: terminology, fallacies, aristotle

<sub>Source: p 114, *With Good Reason, An Introduction to Informal Fallacies* (6 ed, 2000) by [York U. Prof. S. Morris Engel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S._Morris_Engel)</sub>

> Unintended meanings can arise not only from faulty sentence, 
>   structure, as in the case of amphiboly, but also from confusion 
>   to emphasis. The *fallacy of accent** results when (1) a statement 
>   is spoken in a tone of voice not intended (2) certain words are wrongly accented or stressed; or (3) certain words (or even whole sentences and paragraphs) are taken out of context and thus given an emphasis (and therefore a meaning) they were 
>   not meant to have.
>
> **Accent* was the term applied by Arisiotle to misinterpretations 
>   resulting from wards that differ in syllabic accent. An example 
>   in English would be the confusion of *in*valid (meaning "someone ill") and in*val*id (meaning "a faulty argument"). By extension, the term came to be applied In whole words and sentences 
>   chat when similarly misaccented convey a meaning they were 
>   not intended to convey.

Is the last paragraph above correct, because the word [accent](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=accent&allowed_in_frame=0) originates from Latin from PIE without entering Ancient Greek? 'accent' was the [Loan Translation or Calque](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loanword#Linguistic_classification) of the Ancient Greek 'prosodia', but 'prosodia' appears too positively connoted a noun to describe a Logical Fallacy?

Comment: A better term might be "prosodic contour".  Your suspicion is well-motivated; English is accented, French is not, nor was Attic Greek.  But the basic idea is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

See [Sophistical Refutations](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Sophistical_Elenchi):

> [166b1-166b9] An argument depending upon accent [[προσῳδῐ́ᾱ ‎(*prosōidíā*) the tone or pitch of a word](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%CF%80%CF%81%CE%BF%CF%83%E1%BF%B3%CE%B4%CE%AF%CE%B1)] is not easy to construct in unwritten discussion; in written discussions and in poetry it is easier. Thus (e.g.) some people emend Homer against those who criticize as absurd his expression *to men ou katapythetai ombro* [*τὸ μὲν οὖ καταπύθεται ὄμβρῷ*]. For they solve the difficulty by a change of accent, pronouncing the *ou* with an acute accent. [*footnote*: They emend *οὖ* to *οὔ*, ‘Part of which decays in the rain’ to ‘It does not decay in the rain’ (*Iliad*, XXIII 328).] Also, in the passage about Agamemnon’s dream, they say that Zeus did not himself say ‘We grant him the fulfilment of his prayer’ [*δίδομεν δέ οἱ εὖχος ἀρέσθαι*], but that he bade the dream [*διδόναι*] grant it. Instances such as these, then, turn upon the accentuation.

That's all.